# substring till first occurrence of comma in a string

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a string like this:

```
String s = "first link, second link, third link, fourth link"
```

I want to divide each in a separate string and put it in a list of strings like this:

```
List<String> s = ["first link","second link","third link","fourth link"]
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Split](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/split.html) method to create an array from a string

Using your example:

```
String s = "first link, second link, third link, fourth link"    
s.split(", "); // will return ['first link', 'second link', 'third link', 'fourth link'];
```